# ExecutorService.execute() silently exits run() method

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, executorservice

Trying to test that one of my classes can handle being accessed on multiple threads. I have a JUnit test in which I have created a class to implement `Runnable` and run my class.

When I run execute, it reaches a line in the run() method and just exits on that thread without reporting back any issue, I've wrapped it with Try-Catch(Throwable), but still no sign of what's gone wrong.

Here's my code:

```
class ConcurrencyTests {
    class ConcurrentComponentTracker implements Runnable {
        private String component;

        ConcurrentComponentTracker(String component) {
            this.component = component;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
           System.out.printf("Component to track: [%s]\n", component);
           ParserHandler parserHandler = new ParserHandler();
           System.out.println(parserHandler.componentTracker(component));
           }
           catch (Throwable t) {
               t.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }

    @Test
    void runRunner() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        String[] componentsToTrack = {"x", "y", "z"};

        executor.execute(new ConcurrentComponentTracker(componentsToTrack[0]));
        executor.execute(new ConcurrentComponentTracker(componentsToTrack[1]));
        executor.execute(new ConcurrentComponentTracker(componentsToTrack[2]));
    }
}
```

And the output:

`Component to track: [x]`

`Component to track: [y]`

`Component to track: [z]`

It just seems to exit on the ParserHandler instantiation line without reporting anything. When attempting to debug and step into that line, it just skips to the end without letting my inspect the ParserHandler class instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whomever answered in a comment and then deleted it solved the problem for me. My main JUnit thread wasn't waiting for the other threads to finish. So I tacked on these lines to the end and it worked as expected:

```
executor.shutdown();

try {
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I removed the comment when I couldn't reproduce it with a `main` method. This is actually an interesting case: the main thread is terminated only when I test it with JUnit. Running it as a normal java application worked just fine (I didn't know that junit did such things)

Answer (score 0):

JUnit test should actually test and verify result. In this particular case your test produces output which should be verified by the developer/tester, thus this is not automation.
I suggest you to use `Future<?>` to track status of your tasks execution. For `Runnable` tasks `get()` method of `Future<?>` will return `null` if task executed successfully, otherwise it will forward you exception wrapped with `ExecutionException`. Code will look like this:

```
@Test
void runRunner() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    String[] componentsToTrack = {"x", "y", "z"};

    assertNull(executor.submit(new ConcurrentComponentTracker(componentsToTrack[0]).get());
    assertNull(executor.submit(new ConcurrentComponentTracker(componentsToTrack[1]).get());
    assertNull(executor.submit(new ConcurrentComponentTracker(componentsToTrack[2]).get());

    // cleanup and shutdown pool
    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // ignore this
    }
}
```

Before doing so, you should remove `try/catch` block inside your `run()` method.

Another thing you probably can improve is to make executor a field of your test class and manage it with traditional JUnit lifecycle using `@BeforeClass`, `@Before`, ... to initialize, clean between tests, shutdown pool gracefully. Bear in mind that thread pools are not so cheap from resources point of view.

Hope it helps!

**P.S.** if your goal is parallel processing of your `ConcurrentComponentTracker`'s you can store `Future<?>` in some collection and run assertions after all tasks will be submitted.